# What is the use of the order by ASC keyword in an SQL query?

Tags: order-by, database-agnostic

As most, if not all, implementation of SQL use the `ASC` keyword by default in an `ORDER BY` clause when it is omitted.

Are there valid use case for the `ASC` keyword?

I am NOT asking for psychological reasons, opinions, good practices, readability or anything fabricated around SQL that can change from one person's perspective to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really, maybe the query is more readable. `ASC` is like the `AS` keyword, *optional*. - [user237716](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/237716/ergest-basha)

In my team I insist on it. It shows me that they thought about whether it should be *ascending* or *descending*. Otherwise they forgot to think. – [user68670](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/68670/rohit-gupta)

There is a rule: Anything that is not described explicitly can be anything. Never rely on the default settings - in doing so, you lose control of the process. Why save bytes? what to do with them then? Nobody will buy them. – [user150107](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina)